# Vaadin 14 - remove a row of a grid by using rendered delete button

Tags: java, vaadin

My grid refers to a MySQL database table.

```
this.grid   = new Grid<>(Person.class, false);
```

Then i added the columns for my attributes and also a column for a rendered component that is linked to ui which contains my delete button.

```
this.grid.addColumn(RenderedComponent.Renderer(DeleteButton::new))
```

So in every row of the grid there is one Button to delete.

My problem is that i don't know how to get the bean that refers to the row in which the button is.
Because when i have that, i hopefully can do this on button click:

```
new PersonDAO().remove(bean);
```

and then refresh the grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the column renderer, you have access to the item. you just don't use it yet for the button creation. Instead of

```
this.grid.addColumn(RenderedComponent.Renderer(DeleteButton::new))
```

You could do this

```
this.grid.addComponentColumn(item -> new DeleteButton(item));
```

and change your `DeleteButton` class to expect that item in the constructor. You can now use that item to remove it from the database inside the click listener

If you also want to refresh the grid, you would also have to know the grid inside the clicklistener. Either pass the grid too into the DeleteButton, or you can define the clicklistener outside of the DeleteButton class. This will probably make your DeleteButton class obsolete except if it has some custom styling or other enhancments.

```
// using Button instead of DeleteButton for clarity
this.grid.addComponentColumn(item -> new Button("Delete", click -> {
    this.personDao.remove(item); // NEVER instantiate your service or dao yourself, instead inject it into the view
    this.grid.getDataProvider().refresh();
}));
```